# Setting up equations. "Acceleration is proportional to square root of velocity"

Tags: calculus

"Acceleration is proportional to square root of velocity"

Does this mean $A = kv^{1/2}$ ??

Comment: That's exactly what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as:

$$A \propto \sqrt{v} $$

or:

$$A \propto v^{1/2} $$

then, substituting in a constant of proportionality $k$

$$A = kv^{1/2} $$